# How to find parts of elements in NumPy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a NumPy array with different length string elements:

```
array(['*,V*,UV,**,a2*,IR' , 'SB*,V*,UV,**,*,a2*,IR' , '*,V*,a2*' , ...])
```

Each element is a set of abbreviations separated by comma. How to find elements (and their indices) where one of abbreviations is equal ** (double asterisk)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, numpy arrays aren't a good data structure for what you're doing.

You're either going to be using a fixed-length string array (which is memory-inefficient, but can be fast) or an object array (which is inefficent for many short strings, and is generally fairly slow).  Lists are a much more flexible (and faster to iterate through in python) option than numpy object arrays.

It's quite possible that you'd be better off with a list of strings.

However, if you do want to use numpy arrays of strings, you can use the [vectorized string operations in `np.char`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.char.html).

In your case, you'd need to use `find` (the `in` operator won't work here for the same reason you have to do `(x > 5) & (y > 5)` instead of `(x > 5) and (y > 5)` for boolean comparisons of numpy arrays).

For example:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array(['*,V*,UV,**,a2*,IR' , 'SB*,V*,UV,**,*,a2*,IR' , '*,V*,a2*'], 
             dtype=str)
print np.char.find(x, '**') != -1
```

Comment: Problem with `find` is that it'll return True for `'***'` as well.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary - Good point! There is `np.char.split`, as well, but at that point you might as well use a list comprehension as perimosocordiae's answer does.

Answer (score 2):

Just as you would in normal python:

```
for elem in array:
    if '**' in elem.split(','):
        # do something with elem
```

Or if you want a list of them:

```
[elem for elem in array if '**' in elem.split(',')]
```

Alternately, you could vectorize your test function:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: a = np.array(['*,V*,UV,**,a2*,IR' , 'SB*,V*,UV,**,*,a2*,IR' , '*,V*,a2*'])

In [3]: def test(elem):
   ...:     return '**' in elem.split(',')
   ...:

In [4]: vtest = np.vectorize(test)

In [5]: vtest(a)
Out[5]: array([ True,  True, False], dtype=bool)

In [6]: a[vtest(a)]
Out[6]:
array(['*,V*,UV,**,a2*,IR', 'SB*,V*,UV,**,*,a2*,IR'],
      dtype='|S21')
```

Comment: @perimosocordiae Is it possible to write your first answer in single row? I do not need to do something with elements.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary could you explain?

Comment: @user2579566 Not sure what you want, but a list comprehension should do it: `[x for x in a if '**' in x.split(',')]`. If you want an array then pass this list to `numpy.array`.